# How to call multiple curl request with large number of data

Tags: php, curl

i want to hit the url and pass username using curl and eventually get the response back.The issue i am facing is my username array has approximately 45000 entries.I tried achieving it using curl_multi_init but unfortunately it worked for only small chunk of data max for 15 requests simultaneously,otherwise for whole array the page keeps on loading and loading forever and sometimes it gives the memory limit error i.e  Out of memory (allocated 30408704) (tried to allocate 65536 bytes).

```
foreach($username as $u)
{
    $data[]='http://cba.com.pk/hxc/get_details.php?uname='.$u;
}
function multiRequest($data)
{
    $curly = array();
    $result = array();
    $mh = curl_multi_init();
    $ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.A.B.C Safari/525.13';
    foreach ($data as $id => $d) 
    {
        $curly[$id]= curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_URL,$d);
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $ua);
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 20);
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $curly[$id]);

    }
    $running = null;
    do 
    {
        curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
    } while ($running);
    foreach($curly as $id => $c) 
    {
        $result[$id] = curl_multi_getcontent($c);
        curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $c);
    }
    curl_multi_close($mh);
    return $result;
```

Comment: Just out of interest, what are you trying to achieve exactly ? This really doesn't seem like the best approach..

Comment: If this is for data-mining of a 3rd party site, I wouldn't be surprised if your requests are being blocked.. Can you give some context here please ?

Comment: i want to hit the api using curl to get the response for large number of data

Comment: its not data-mining of a third party site its related to my office work the api is our own

Comment: If the API is your own, I would suggest you query the database directly internally, all you are doing is hammering a php script for requests of individual requests, simultaneous or not, its not efficient. As for your question i would suggest you keep the 15 in parallel and do it that way, there is no good reason to have 45k in parallel.